# IIS7 wildcard mapping for dynamic subdomains

Tags: iis-7, dns, wildcard-subdomain

I have this setup in IIS:
 1- Default website
 2- Site1: binding test.example.com:10.10.10.10:80

I want to have *.test.example.com to point to Site1 so if I go to test1.test.example.com I will see the application on Site1, note that I have in the DNS a multiple A records:
  test.example.com   10.10.10.10
  *.test.example.com 10.10.10.10

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably better suited for serverfault. Long story short though, this isn't possible in IIS. Check out [this post](http://forums.iis.net/p/1095760/2029983.aspx) in the IIS forum.